# Is it possible to query an element in Firestore by key without knowing which collection it belongs to?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

Using AngularFire2, Angular, Firebase Firestore, and one of my records models the relationship between a user and different types of objects.

```
/*
Represents a reaction that a user has towards some object in the system.
*/
export interface Reaction{

// The id of the user making that reaction
userId? : string;

// The id of the object that is being reacted to. Place, Org, List, Offer
objectId? : string;

}
```

As you can see the only thing being stored is the key of an object and not its type or which collection it belongs to. I'm wondering how it would be possible at a later time, to query the reactions and then from there get the objects purely based on their key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must know the name of the collection (and possibly subcollection) of a document in order to obtain it.  There's no concept of a query that can get a document without knowledge of a collection.

Comment: Oh ok... Thanks Doug. Do you know if the keys are universally unique or just unique within their own collection?

Comment: They're unique within the collection.  You can think of collections as part of a unique path to a document: `collection1/doc1/subcollection1/doc1`